# No of ways of making Garland using different kinds of flowers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Question: There are 6n flowers of one type and 3 flowers of another type, total no of garlands possible?

My approach-:
I have considered 3 cases
Case 1. Garland contains only 6n  flowers
No of possible ways $= \frac{(6n-1)!}{2}$

Case 2. Garland contains only type containing 3 flowers
No of permutations$= \frac{2!}{2}$

Case 3. Garland has both types of flowers
No of permutations $= \frac{(6n+2)!}{2*6n!*3!}$

Total permutations$= (6n+2)!/(2*6n!*3!) + 1 + (6n-1)!/2$

Is this approach correct or have I missed/considered some cases? What approach should be used for such questions?

Comment: Are individual flowers distinguishable? Also, it's not clear how many flowers are in a garland. Can it have only one flower? Judging by the question, you probably need to use all flowers to make a garland, but it would be nice to see complete text of the problem.

Comment: Individual Flowers of same type are not distinguishable. There is no other information  about  Garland containing only 1 flower, given in question

Comment: Then you have to assume that all flowers need to be used to form a garland. Look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) This problem is equivalent to placing $3$ bars among $2n$ stars (and you need to account for circular arrangement).

Comment: I believe all the flowers are supposed to be used in the garland.  Based on your calculations, it appears you are assuming the garland can be turned over.  What makes this calculation tricky is the case in which there are $2n$ flowers of the first type between each flower of the second type.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig  What  I have assumed that Flowers of one type are together and Flowers of another type are together in garland. Why this assumption flawed?

Comment: The usual assumption is that flowers of the same type are indistinguishable.  Therefore, what matters is the relative placement of the flowers.  Also, if all the flowers are used in the garland, we are only concerned with your third case, which is handled in the linked problem.  Most people counted the number of distinguishable garlands up to rotation.  As for Samar Imam Zaidi's answer, he may be taking invariance under reflection into account.